# open ShowModalDialog of Javascript from asp.net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to open ShowModalDialog of Javascript from asp.net code behind (C#). Please provide me the code if possible and one more thing which i want to mention that , i m using Script manager on my page from where i want to open the pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call javascript function from code behind ....

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"hwa","Samplefn();",true);
```

write the following code ...in javascript:

```
function samplefn()
{
 $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
}
```

the  above code used to open model dialog

```
$(function() {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                minHeight: 50,
                position: [300, 50],
                height: 'auto',
                width: 400,
                modal: true
            });
        });
```

otherwise you can directly open model dialog from code behind..

```
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"hwa"," $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');",true);
```